# Is there a queue copy program available for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer, queue

When copying a lot of files all from different locations to the same location, using Windows Explorer, Windows always creates multiple copy processes, slowing everything down.

How can I queue copy actions in Windows 7?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy) for this. Simply a *much better tool than the default* copy handler for Windows.

And it handles file copies sequentially instead of trying to multitask everything simultaneously resulting in NO performance.

<sub>Note: TeraCopy is free for non-commercial use only. For commercial use you need to buy a license.</sub>

Comment: I haven't tried it on W7 yet but agree that teracopy is the dogs danglies. queues items, much more granular control over duplicates, reports any skips/failures, and all seamless as in overrides the default copy/paste mechanism so Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v still works.

Comment: I've tried it on win7 and I can confirm that is works smoothly.

Comment: yeah, but Toucan will give you for free some features that you have to pay for with teracopy...

Comment: Teracopy works well for me on both 32 and 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Best program for anything after basic copying

Comment: I also installed this, on Win7 64bits and it works smoothly! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Copy Handler (win32)](http://www.copyhandler.com/).

Free and Open-source, multi-language, tray operation, loads of options for filtering, threads, different buffer modes, display, file handling, start & resume on boot etc.

Answer (score 3):

For those addicted to (or just with a fondness for) the command line, there is always:

[RoboCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx)

which is shipped "in the box" with Vista and Windows 7, too:

```
C:\Users\jeff>robocopy

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Aug 01 21:50:48 2011

       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?    

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

Comment: RoboCopy is great, but does it help with queued copying?

Comment: You could queue multiple instances of RoboCopy for multiple copy operations.

Comment: Do you mean queueing using a batch file or such? If so, can't you do that with any copy program?

Comment: Yes, either with a batch file to carry out multiple copy operations in series or multiple instances of RoboCopy running from the command line if you wanted to do them in parallel (when copying from/to different sources and destinations for example). I think it would depend on whether we are talking about "one off" file copies or files which need copying regularly from one place to another.

Answer (score 2):

PerigeeCopy is a good, easy and powerful alternative: http://jstanley.pingerthinger.com/pscopy.html

Answer (score 1):

Or, use Toucan

http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan

or ICE Mirror .

http://www.ice-graphics.com/ICEMirror/DownloadE.html

Answer (score 1):

[**Total Commander**](http://www.ghisler.com/)

> Copy Dialog
>
> With the button F2 Queue, the selected
>   files will be added to the last opened
>   background transfer manager. This is
>   useful to copy many big files one
>   after the other, which is more
>   efficient than multiple in parallel in
>   the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MyFileQueue, a program that I developed:

http://ludmon.com.au/myfilequeue/

I wrote this file queue program to help my colleagues and I to copy our large files between external hard drives. Using MyFileQueue we simply build a list of files in a queue using a file manager like interface, then when we've picked all the files we click the start button. MyFileQueue then runs through the queue one file at a time eliminating the USB bottleneck. There are a few other features such as runtime stats, pause/resume etc.

Comment: Hi! Promoting your own products is fine if you disclose that, but could you maybe expand your answer a bit and explain how it solves the problem, how to use it, etc?

Comment: I wrote the file queue program to help my colleagues and I to copy our large files between external hard drives. Using MyFileQueue we simply build a list of files in a queue using a file manager like interface, then when we've picked all the files we click the start button. MyFileQueue then runs through the queue one file at a time eliminating the USB bottleneck. There are a few other features such as runtime stats, pause/resume etc. Thanks for allowing me to share this information in your forum. Cheers, Steve

Answer (score 0):

I use [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) on all my Windows 7 machines.

> TeraCopy is designed to copy and move files at the maximum possible speed. It skips bad files during the copying process, and then displays them at the end of the transfer so that you can see which ones need attention. TeraCopy can automatically check the copied files for errors by calculating their CRC checksum values. It also provides a lot more information about the files being copied than its Windows counterpart. TeraCopy integrates with Windows Explorer's right-click menu and can be set as the default copy handler.

Answer (score -1):

[FF Copy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffcopy/) is a free open source utility (last updated on 03/12/2013) that may suit your needs.

> FF Copy is a tool that allows you to queue up file copy operations in Windows. Copy operations can be paused, stopped and resumed and will auto-resume in case of temporarily unavailable source/target.

[image]

Comment: Why was this down voted?