# Is it possible to auto-pause / -sequential copy multiple files in Windows 10 copy queue?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer

If I copy multiple files in separate copy processes they will be performed parallel (total 72,5 MB/s):
[image: w10 parallel copy queue]

But as my target drive is a HDD it reaches more transfer speed if I pause the other copy processes (92 vs 72 MB/s):
[image: w10 sequential copy queue]

Is it possible to force this behaviour by default?

Comment: Why does it matter? You still have to finish copying the other files ... the total time will be the same anyway ...

Comment: No, @DavidPostill  - it is actually _significantly faster_ overall to do it in sequence than in parallel. Could be head movement of the disk, swap efforts, or just poor Windows programming

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or different file management software for this use case? Currently in the middle of moving a bunch of folders around and this drives me nuts.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/9284/60795

Answer (score 0):

Do the copy from a batch file that uses dummy file as a lock.
This is based on the fact that a file being written is locked, so any attempt
to write it will fail.

Use this (untested) batch file as replacement for the copy command:

```
:loop
2>nul (
  >C:\path\to\lockfile (
    copy %*
  )
)||goto :loop
```